# Validate alphanumeric strings in PHP

Tags: php

I'm not sure if alphanumeric is the correct term but I would like to validate characters that are in a combination of strings, integers and dashes. Example: `yui-4444-99`. So far, i've tried intval, strcmp, ctype_alnum and preg_match but it doesnt really work.

sample:

```php
<?php
if (ctype_alnum($string1) == ctype_alnum($string2)) {
    echo "nice!";       
} else {
}
```

my txt.file

```
abc-1234-99
Cedric
93482812
cedric@hotmail.com
---------------------------------------------
def-4332-99
Wendy
98238432
wendy@hotmail.com
Guitar
2010
Yamaha
Scratches on the side
Used
---------------------------------------------
fgh-4567-99
Wendy
98238432
wendy@hotmail.com
---------------------------------------------
yui-4444-99
Wendy
98238432
wendy@hotmail.com
---------------------------------------------
vbn-5624-99
jason
98238432
wendy@hotmail.com
---------------------------------------------
```

This is how i extracted my values to diff variables.

```
<?php
    
$handle = @fopen('listings.txt', "r");
$row = 0;
$count = 0;
$line0 = [];
$line1 = [];
$line2 = [];
$line3 = [];
$line4 = [];
$line5 = [];
$line6 = [];
$line7 = [];
$line8 = [];
$line9 = [];
    
if ($handle) { 
   while (!feof($handle)) { 
       $store = fgets($handle, 4096); 
       if ($row == 10){
        $row = 0;
        $count++;
    }
    if ($row == 0) 
    {
        $line0[] = strval($store);
    }
    else if($row == 1) {
$line1[] = strval($store);}
    else if($row == 2) {
$line2[] = strval($store);}
    else if($row == 3) {
$line3[] = strval($store);}
    else if($row == 4) {
$line4[] = strval($store);}
    else if($row == 5) {
$line5[] = strval($store);}
    else if($row == 6) {
$line6[] = strval($store);}
    else if($row == 7) {
$line7[] = strval($store);}
    else if($row == 8) {
$line8[] = strval($store);}
    
    $row++;
   }
        
      $sn = 0;
      
      
    if (isset($_GET['sn'])) {
        $sn=$_GET['sn'];
    }
      $item = count($line0);
      
        for ($c=0; $c<$item; $c++)
    {
        if((intval($line0[$c]) == intval($sn))) {
        echo $line0[$c],"<br>";
        echo $line1[$c],"<br>";
        echo $line2[$c],"<br>";
        echo $line3[$c],"<br>";
        echo $line4[$c],"<br>";
        echo $line5[$c],"<br>";
        echo $line6[$c],"<br>";
        echo $line7[$c],"<br>";
        echo $line8[$c],"<br>";
        break;
        }
    }
    ?>

    
    
    
    <?php
   fclose($handle); 
} 

    ?>
```

Comment: You want just to compare two texes?

Comment: yes, to make sure both are these variables have the same characters

Comment: ok sir hold on, its abit more complicated than that, i apologize for not elaborating

Comment: So, im doing a search box, so the 1st variable will be the text entered and it will pass it over to the result page where it will compare it with the 2nd variable.

Comment: @azibom will take a look in abit, thanks

Comment: @AlivetoDie updated, so my $string2 will contain an array of the first line of each element. "abc-1234-99, def-4332-99"

Comment: @AlivetoDie Updated, sorry if its abit messy

Comment: "sn" is the search box text aka the $string1

Comment: why are you using sth like this `line1`, `line2` , you can easy use the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to shorten out code of reading file using `file()`.

Also needs to rectify comparison code as well.

Do like below:

```
<?php

$string2 = file('listings.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

$foundArray = [];

foreach($string2 as $string){
    if (ctype_alnum($string1) == ctype_alnum($string)) {
        $foundArray[] = $string; 
    }
}

echo "found matches :".print_r($foundArray,true);
```

Sample output: https://3v4l.org/Vt4OE

Answer (score 2):

Starting from PHP 8, you can compare strings to their numeric equivalent:

```
$test = ['', 'a23', '23', 'abc'];
foreach ($test as $string) {
  echo ($string != (int) $string ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
TRUE
TRUE
FALSE
TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just compare the first part of them, you can use this code:

```php
<?php
$string1 = "sdf-98-s";
$stringArray = ["sdf", "asd"];

$myArray = explode('-', $string1); // make the array from string
$firstElement = reset($myArray); // choose the first element

if (in_array($firstElement, $stringArray)) {
    echo "Find it!";       
} else {
    echo "Fail to find it!";       
}
```

Comment: so the only way is to explode the dashes so it can validate?

Comment: what is the problem with this solution?

Comment: my 2nd variable which is $string2 will be reading an array of these strings from a txt.file. so my search box text which is $string1 will have to compare with all the other strings in my txt.file.